# UIBarButtonItem doesn't resize automatically when the device is rotated

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 1 UIBarButoonItem on UINavigationBar.now as i'm moving view from portrait to landscape mode my UINavigationBar resizes Automatically but UIBarButtonItem not autoresizes 
My UIBarButtonItem is at rightmost position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

barbuttonitems aren't supposed to resize...
That's something you will have to do manually if you want it

Comment: Here is a good site to get you started with a custom sized button for a toolbar or navigation bar http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/04/17/how-to-change-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-the-iphone-toolbar/